# PHP transaction not rolling back

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have some PHP code that reads a spreadsheet using PHPExcel and imports the data into a MySQL database. (innoDB)  If the import encounters a duplicate record in the database it's supposed to fail and rollback all prior inserts.  The rollback is not working, I wrote this small program that functions the same way.

```
$conn = null;
try {

$conn=new mysqli("myServer","user","password", "moveforward");
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);

$sql="insert into series (seriesLocation,seriesName,seriesDate) values('1','2','2013-05-21')";
echo "Executing query 1<br>";
$conn->query($sql);
if($conn->error!="") {
    $sqlError=$conn->error;
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Rollback complete<br>";
    throw new Exception($sqlError);
}

//This will throw a duplicate exception
echo "Exceuting query 2<br>";
$conn->query($sql);
if($conn->error!="") { 
    $sqlError=$conn->error;
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Rollback complete<br>";
    throw new Exception($sqlError);
}
echo "You shouldn't be here<br>";

$conn->commit();
echo "Transactions comitted<br>";

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
}
$conn->close();
echo "Done<br>";
```

In looking at the php manual and checking other posts on here this looks like it should work.  When I run it I get this:

```
Executing query 1
Exceuting query 2
Rollback complete
Exception: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'seriesName'
Done
```

Yet when I check the database the data from the first insert is in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess your tables doesn't use an appropriate engine

http://php.net/mysqli.autocommit

> This function doesn't work with non transactional table types (like MyISAM or ISAM).

However, it is much easier to use `INSERT IGNORE` (or `REPLACE` depending on what should be the correct behaviour) instead. In this case the duplicated rows are silently ignored (or replace the existing one (`REPLACE`)). Of course this doesn't work, if you want to know, which are the duplicates.

Comment: The default storage engine is set to innodb....is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Look on what the tables _really_ running on. There is a good chance, that they use the same engine as the one defined as default, but I for myself would have a look at it ;)

Comment: That was it.  I never realized you could mix and match like that.  I changed it and now it's working perfectly.  Thank you!