# PDO: How can I run multiple prepared statements in a transaction?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, prepared-statement

Using PDO, I am trying to run two prepared statements within a transaction. I only want the second prepared statement to run if the first one executes successfully and vice versa.

```
//Open Database Connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pwd);

//Set Error Handling
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Run First Prepared Statement
$sql = 'UPDATE listers SET
        first_name = :first_name,
        last_name = :last_name,
        address = :address,
        apt = :apt,
        city = :city,
        state = :state,
        zip_1 = :zip_1,
        phone_prefix = :phone_prefix,
        phone_first = :phone_first,
        phone_last = :phone_last 
        WHERE lister_id = :lister_id';
try {   
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':first_name', $_POST['first_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->bindParam(':last_name', $_POST['last_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(':apt', $_POST['apt'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->bindParam(':city', $_POST['city'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->bindParam(':state', $_POST['state'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->bindParam(':zip_1', $_POST['zip_1'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $result->bindParam(':phone_prefix', $phone_1_prefix, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $result->bindParam(':phone_first', $phone_1_first, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $result->bindParam(':phone_last', $phone_1_last, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    $result->bindParam(':lister_id', $_GET['lister_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 

    $result->execute();


    //Run Second Prepared Statement
    $current_date = time(); //Current Date/time in Unix format

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO hidddstory_details SET
            history_id = :history_id, 
            listing_type = "lister",  
            date_added = :date_added,
            listing_id = :listing_id';

    $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);                                                    
    $result->bindParam(':history_id', $account_edited_admin, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
    $result->bindParam(':date_added', $current_date, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $result->bindParam(':listing_id', $row['lister_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                  
    $result->execute();

    $dbh->commit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
     $error = '<div id="error"><p class="error_message">The account could not be edited due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p></div>';
     $dbh->rollBack();
     echo errorHandle($e);
}
```

When I load the page without any syntax errors, it runs the prepared statements correctly. When I purposefully add some letters to the history_details table name, as you can see above, it displays the error message relating to the incorrect table name, as it should. Unfortunately though, it doesn't rollback the first prepared statement, so when I check the listers table, it has actually updated that table, which it shouldn't.

How can I run multiple prepared statements in a transaction?

Comment: it the table engine you are using innodb?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP transaction not rolling back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821167/php-transaction-not-rolling-back)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine the storage engine for the table you are trying to perform transactions on to ensure that it in fact supports transactions. As far as I know InnoDB is on the only format that currently supports transactions. Engines that do not support transactions will silently do nothing, no errors will be issued nor will any rollback be done.

Comment: Yeah, that might be it. It is currently set to MyISAM. IS there anything I should be concerned about when switching it to InnoDB?

Comment: @zeckdude performance may take a slight hit given the need for transaction log overhead but I haven't noticed anything earth shattering when I changed my tables over. and another thing to watch out for is innodb supports transactions but it doesn't support nested transactions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how nested transactions work. The example I have posted above is as complex as it gets on my site, but if you have any links that explain more about nested transactions, I would love to know.

Your solution worked, so thanks alot!